# The expression Cycles[{}] cannot be used as a part specification?

Tags: warning-messages

I am trying to do the following:

```
S = GroupElements[SymmetricGroup[4]];
Nest[PermutationProduct[S[[2]], S[[#]]] &, 2, 3]
```

But this yields the following errors:

- Part::pkspec1: The expression Cycles[{}] cannot be used as a part specification.
- Part::pkspec1: The expression Cycles[{{3,4}}][PermutationProduct]{Cycles[{}],Cycles[{{3,4}}],Cycles[{{2,3}}],Cycles[{{2,3,4}}],Cycles[{{2,4,3}}],Cycles[{{2,4}}],Cycles[{{1,2}}],Cycles[{{1,2},{3,4}}],Cycles[{{1,2,3}}],Cycles[{{1,2,3,4}}],<<14>>}[[Cycles[{}]]] cannot be used as a part specification.

I don't understand what is happening, I don't know why it is using `Cycles[{}]` as part specification, shouldn't it be using an integer as part specification?

Comment: If you look at S it consists of a long list starting with: {Cycles[{}], Cycles[{{3, 4}}], Cycles[{{2, 3}}]...}

Comment: @bills Yes, it should take another element of that list and apply the permutation product. If I write `PermutationProduct[S[[2]],S[[2]]]`, it computes without problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [`Nest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest.html) documentation,

> `Nest[f,expr,n]`
>
> gives an expression with `f` applied `n` times to `expr`.

Your code starts off by defining

```
S = GroupElements[SymmetricGroup[4]];
```

which equals

```
{Cycles[{}], Cycles[{{3, 4}}], Cycles[{{2, 3}}], Cycles[{{2, 3, 4}}], ... }.
```

With this in place, when you attempt to do

```
Nest[f, 2, 3]
```

with

```
f = PermutationProduct[S[[2]], S[[#]]] &
```

the code does three things in sequence:

- First, it applies `f` to `2`, which returns `f[2]` = `PermutationProduct[S[[2]], S[[#]]] &[2]` = `PermutationProduct[S[[2]], S[[2]]]` = `PermutationProduct[Cycles[{{3, 4}}], Cycles[{{3, 4}}]]` = `Cycles[{}]`.
- It then attempts to apply `f` to *that* previous result, so it tries to calculate `f[Cycles[{}]]`, and this equals `PermutationProduct[S[[2]], S[[#]]] &[Cycles[{}]]`, which simplifies to `PermutationProduct[S[[2]], S[[ Cycles[{}] ]]]`.

  This is where the code jams up -- you are trying to calculate `S[[ Cycles[{}] ]]`, i.e., the `Cycles[{}]`-th part of `S`, and that's not going to work. The whole thing returns itself, unevaluated, and this is where the error message

  > Part::pkspec1: The expression Cycles[{}] cannot be used as a part specification.

  gets generated.
- As a third step, the code then attempts to nest `f` a *third* time, i.e., it tries to calculate `PermutationProduct[S[[2]], S[[ x ]]]`, where the part specification `x` is now the result from the previous step, i.e., an unevaluated mess with head `PermutationProduct`. This generates the second, messier `Part::pkspec1` error message.

In other words, your code is mostly asking Mathematica to do calculations which don't really make sense. Unfortunately, the code itself doesn't really give enough information about what you *really* want to calculate, so it's hard to give a definitive answer about how to fix it.

---

As my best guess, what you want is to take `S[[2]]` and then multiply it repeatedly with `S[[2]]`? If so, the correct expression would be

```
Nest[PermutationProduct[S[[2]], #] &, S[[2]], 3]
```

which starts off with a group element as the `expr` input of `Nest`, and then applies a function, `g=PermutationProduct[S[[2]], #] &` which has the property that it always returns a group element when fed a group element, so it can be correctly nested.

---

(Alternatively, if you want to work at the level of integers, you can try to use [`Position`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html) to recover which element of `S` got returned by the `PermutationProduct`, so using something like

```
Nest[Position[S, PermutationProduct[S[[2]], S[[#]]]][[1, 1]] &, 2, 3]
```

(where the `[[1,1]]` is to break the list returned by `Position`, in the hopes that it only ever carries a single element). But this is messier and more fragile, and I wouldn't recommend it much.)

Comment: Yes, you guessed correctly. Thanks for the reply. This is so odd, whenever `#` appears, something is going to behave in some very unexpected way, perhaps due to my low level of expertise in Mathematica, I am not very fluent in this.

Comment: @BillyRubina If that's the case, then I would recommend switching from the shorthand notation `f[#]&` to the equivalent notation `Function[x,f[x]]`, using the full form of [`Function`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html). This will force you to give the variable (here, `x`) a suitably descriptive name, which is useful discipline to guard against this type of slip-up.